# Вывод на экран слов последовательности, которые отличны от последнего слова

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, списки

> Данная последовательность, содержащая от 2 до 20 слов, в каждом из которых от 1 до 8 строчных, между соседними словами - не менее одного пробела, за последним словом - точка.
>
> Реализовать вывод на экран тех слов последовательности, которые отличны от последнего слова и удовлетворяют свойства симметричности.

Не могу понять, почему код работает не правильно:

```
Text=input("ведите слова")
print(Text,end=".")
if len(Text.split())>20:
    print()
    print("введите меньше слов")
elif len(Text.split())<2:
    print()
    print("введите больше слов")
Text_1=Text.split()
for i in Text_1:
    if i==Text_1[-1]:
        Text_1.remove(i)
    elif Text_1[0]==Text[-1]:
        Text_1.remove[0]
print()
print(Text_1,end=".")
print()
for b in Text_1:
    b=b.split()
    if b.reverse not in Text_1:
        Text_1.remove(b)#ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list-ошибка
print(Text_1)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте пример исходных данных и желаемый результат.

Answer (score 1):

*Главная* проблема вашей программы (дважды):

- В цикле `for` проходите тот-же самым списком, *из которого в нём удаляете члены* и тем его *изменяете*.

  Нужно проходить через *копию* списка (которую возможно просто получить созданием *отрезка со всеми элементами* , т.е. добавлением `[:]`за его имя.)

*Вторая проблема* - невозможно применить метод `.reverse()` к *строке* - сначала нужно её переводить в *список символов* (например функцией `list()`).

*Но а третья* - ваша программа всё равно работает *тоже после ввода неправильного количества слов,* только она выдает об этом сообщение. Нужно тогда *снова (и снова) задать вопрос* (в цикле `while`), пока количество слов не будет правильным.

Я немножко переработал вашу программу и использовал *более удобные имена для переменных,* только со *строчными* буквами - см. [PEP 8 - руководство по написанию кода на Python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id28) - и вставил где-то пробелы (см. там-же).

```
while True:
    text = input("Ведите слова: ")
    words = text.split()

    if len(words) > 20:
        print("Введите меньше слов.")
        print()
        continue                        # прекратить, а снова задать вопрос
    elif len(words) < 2:
        print("Введите больше слов.")
        print()
        continue
    break                               # прекратить весь цикл

last_word = words[-1][:-1]              # [:-1] для удаления точки
words = words[:-1]                      # последнее слово уже не надо

for word in words[:]:                   # [:] строит копию списка
    if word == last_word:
        words.remove(word)

for word in words[:]:                   # [:] строит копию списка
    letters = list(word)
    letters.reverse()
    reversed_word = "".join(letters)
    if word != reversed_word:
        words.remove(word)

print(words)
```

---

*Примечание:*

Вместо пары команд

```
last_word = words[-1][:-1]              # [:-1] для удаления точки
words = words[:-1]                      # последнее слово уже не надо
```

можно применить команду

```
last_word = words.pop()[:-1]
```